# Immutable.JS Seq / lazy map best practices for performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, immutable.js

I like to use immutable.js with Preact. They work well together because React/Preact's state interacts badly with containers unless the containers are immutable.

A situation I found myself running into ([here is a self contained example](https://github.com/mcclure/ts-hello/tree/libp2p-preact) ; see branch libp2p-preact, source src/index.tsx; it's TypeScript with JSX) is I have a Immutable container full of strings, and I need to render them as JSX. The way I'd normally do that is to create an array of JSX.Elements and inline them into a JSX stanza. So in the example at one point I have an `OrderedSet<List> userList`:

```
const users = userList.toArray().map(
  s => <div className="Id">{s}</div>
)
return <div className="ListBox">
  <div className="List">{users}</div>
</div>
```

However: I can think of a number of different ways I could create that `JSX.Element[] users`.

1. Let ES6 do the map

   ```
   const users = userList.toArray().map(s => <div>{s}</div>)
   ```
2. Let `Immutable.OrderedSet` do the map

   ```
   const users = userList.map(s => <div>{s}</div>).toArray()
   ```
3. Let `Immutable.Seq` do the map

   ```
   const users = userList.toSeq().map(s => <div>{s}</div>).toArray()
   ```

I *assume* 2 is the worst option because I *think* that actually creates an entire second temporary OrderedSet, which is surely more heavyweight than an array, and I don't think any lazy behavior occurs.

However, in principle, 3 could be better because Seq does everything "lazy". So here is my question: Is (3) actually better than (1)? And if so, why?

If you ask: "better how?", what I'm concerned with is amount of garbage created, and number of times scanned over the list. My time with C# has left me irrationally avoidant of creating unnecessary large garbage arrays.

My *assumption* is that (3) is better than (1), especially if userList is large, because (1) will create an array with N string elements, then create a second array with N div elements created by running the map function; whereas (3) will wait to build anything until toArray is called, and then it will iterate over userList building an array of divs directly. Both ways will create garbage, but in the case of (3) it will be one or two small seq() objects whereas in the case of (1) the garbage will be potentially a full N-length array. But I do not know if either immutable.js, or Javascript VMs, work this way in practice.

(Note Preact is probably not important to this question; the important thing is I have a Immutable collection of identifiers and I want to convert it to an array with a simple map fn done on each element.)

Answer (score 2):

The truth is that you can do better than all three options you have mentioned. As an `OrderedSet` is an iterable, and you are aiming to create a plain Array from it, you can use the ES6 standard `Array.from` function with its second callback argument (a mapper):

```
const users = Array.from(userList, s => <div>{s}</div>)
```

Comment: To my suprise, `.valueSeq().map((v) => (<div>{v}</div>)).toArray()` is faster than the Array.from approach (tested in chrome)